# Create a button to toggle flex-direction between row and column for a style

Tags: javascript, css, button, flexbox

I am tying to create a button that will toggle a style flex-direction between "row" and "column"

The code I tried was based on some other code that I used for toggling the display between "flex" and "none".

I can't use Id's because there a multiple non contiguous element.

**I TRIED THE CODE BELOW**

```js
function setDisplay(className, displayValue) {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i].style.flexDirection = displayValue;
    }
}
function showResponsive() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
      if (el.style.flex-direction === "column") {
          el.style.flex-direction = "row";
      } else {
          el.style.flex-direction = "column";
      }
    });
}
```

```css
.green{
    background:green;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.red{
    background:red;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.black{
    background:black;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

.main{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column
}
```

```html
<div><i>Click switch</i></div>
<div>
  <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="showResponsive()" >
      <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>  
</div>             
                    
<div class="main"> 
  <div class="green"></div>  
  <div  class="red"></div>  
  <div class="black"></div>
</div>
```

The code above is based on the code below which works for changing the style.display between "flex" and "none"

```
function setDisplay(className, displayValue) {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i].style.flexDirection = displayValue;
    }
}
function showResponsive() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
      if (el.style.flex-direction === "column") {
          el.style.flex-direction = "row";
      } else {
          el.style.flex-direction = "column";
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's style.flexDirection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your JavaScript code with the following code:

```js
function showResponsive () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
      if (el.style.flexDirection === "column") {
          el.style.flexDirection = "row";
      } else {
          el.style.flexDirection = "column";
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property names on the style object are in camel-case and not kebab-case. So when setting the flex direction use:

```
el.style.flexDirection = "row";
```